# inserting data using object oriented program using mvc framework

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to add students in the database but the the students are not been added to database.

the code for the controller is as follows:

```
public function add_student(){
    $this->load->model('Stud_Model');
    $data=array(
    'roll_no'=>$this->input->post('roll_no'),
    'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
    'role'=>$this->input->post('role'),
    );
    $this->Stud_Model->insert($data);

    $query=$this->db->get("stud");
    $data['records']=$query->result();
    $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data);
}
```

the code for the model is as follows:

```
public function insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('stud',$data);
    if($this->db->insert('stud',$data)){
        return true;
    }
}
```

the code for the view is as follows:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('Stud_controller/add_student');
    echo form_label('Roll No.:');
    echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','role'=>'roll_no'));
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_label('name:');
    echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name','role'=>'name'));
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_label('Role:');
    echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','role'=>'role'));
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Add'));
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: 1st of all: in your model you're calling twice db insert. Leave only one. Then, check the result of the insert if things go bad: ...{ return true; } else { echo "Error in insert", die; }, and finally, if necessary add $last_sql = $this->db->last_query(); echo $sql; to find out what are you really doing in the db.

Comment: ya that i did it but still nothing is happening even no errors are been displayed.

Comment: what error you are getting after insert data ?

Comment: on your modal try `$data = array()`  and `public function insert($data = array()){`

Comment: So, if you have add $last_sql = $this->db->last_query(); echo $last_sql; die; for debbuging, what do you get? What's last query performed actually?

Answer (score 0):

```
        for model 
         public function insert($data)
           {
            return $this->db->insert('stud',$data);   
           }

        for retrive data in model

          public function GetAllStudent()
             {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('stud');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result();
             }
    for retrive data in controller 
    $data['all_std_info'] = $this->Stud_Model->GetAllStudent();
```